# How to pass value from index.html to main.ts in angular

Tags: angular

i am having one function in index.html, once i get the response from index.html then and then only with that response i should be able to trigger main.ts file in angular 11

```
function makeAjaxRequest(val) {
  debugger;
  var dataO = {
    email:val
};

var json = JSON.stringify(dataO);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://google.com",
    data: json,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        //call main.ts from here.
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: why do you want to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what starts your angular located in main.ts

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

You can move your logic there

```
function makeAjaxRequest(val) {
  debugger;
  var dataO = {
    email:val
};

var json = JSON.stringify(dataO);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://google.com",
    data: json,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        //call main.ts from here.
        platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
           .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
  });
}
```